# How to pause azure pipeline execution for several seconds?

Tags: azure, pipeline, sleep

I am using Maria DB docker image for integration tests. I start it in an Azure pipeline via the following commands:

```
      docker pull <some_azure_repository>/databasedump:<tag_number>
      docker run -d --publish 3306:3306 <some_azure_repository>/databasedump:<tag_number>
```

And after that integration tests, written in Python, are started.
But when the code tries to connect to the Maria DB database, mysql error is returned.

```
+ 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

Maybe the reason for that is, that the Maria DB database is big and it needs some seconds to be started.
So my question is whether there is a way to set a sleep of several second in a pipeline execution? In a script or bash section.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a delay step into your pipelines yaml file between the setup of your docker image and your test execution.

```
# Delay v1
# Delay further execution of a workflow by a fixed time.
- task: Delay@1
  inputs:
    delayForMinutes: '0' # string. Required. Delay Time (minutes). Default: 0.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/delay-v1?view=azure-pipelines

Comment: Unfortunately a delay couldn't be added, as the tests run in a job, but  - powershell: |
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 120  did the job